# svn odd behavior: hangs forever on a single file when importing into svn repository

Tags: svn, netbeans, repository, commit, lag

I'm using netbeans and have exported a project in order to create a new project using its source on my svn repository.

i am right clicking on the project name and clicking "import into subversion repository"  and it will begin committing the files.  However, it is hanging on a single file and wont finish the commit.  If I delete that file, it seems to find another file to get stuck on eventually?  What gives, why can't I commit my new project?

Comment: Have you checked the availability of your repository with some repo browser?

Comment: i can browse the directory using firefox.  it does get created, but i dont see any files inside the directory as netbeans is transferring the data

Comment: From where have you exported the project which sources you are trying to use?

Comment: i have project1 in my htdocs dir, i have exported it as project2 within my htdocs dir

Comment: Your subversion repository is on your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the file svn hangs on. I had a similar issue, seems this is due to missing read permission for that file.